# How to have python function run only while key is pressed?

Tags: python, robotics

I am trying to make a simple program where when you hold 'w' it goes forward using `forward ()` but when you let go, it stops the motors using `stop()`. Currently, I can only get it to continuously go forward when 'w' is pressed and only stop when another key is pressed.
Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
 # so that script can be run from Brickman

 import termios, tty, sys, time
 from ev3dev.ev3 import *

 # attach large motors to ports B and C, medium motor to port A
 motor_left = LargeMotor('outA')
 motor_right = LargeMotor('outD')
 motor_a = MediumMotor('outC')

 #==============================================

 def getch():
     fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
     old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
     tty.setcbreak(fd)
     ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
     termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)

     return ch

 #==============================================

 def fire():
    motor_a.run_timed(time_sp=3000, speed_sp=600)

 #==============================================

 def forward():
    motor_left.run_forever(speed_sp=1050)
    motor_right.run_forever(speed_sp=1050)

 #==============================================

 def back():
    motor_left.run_forever(speed_sp=-1050)
    motor_right.run_forever(speed_sp=-1050)

 #==============================================

 def left():
    motor_left.run_forever(speed_sp=-1050)
    motor_right.run_forever(speed_sp=1050)

 #==============================================

 def right():
    motor_left.run_forever(speed_sp=1050)
    motor_right.run_forever(speed_sp=-1050)

 #==============================================

 def stop():
    motor_left.run_forever(speed_sp=0)
    motor_right.run_forever(speed_sp=0)

 #==============================================

 print("ready")
    k = getch()
    print(k)
    if k == 'w':
       forward()
    if k == 's':
       back()
    if k == 'a':
       left()
    if k == 'd':
       right()
    if k == 'f':
       fire()
    if k == ' ':
       stop()
    if k == 'q':
       stop()
       exit()
```

Any idea on how to make it so stop() runs when 'w' is unpressed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/)'s KEYUP and KEYDOWN functionality. Following is a snippet of code that uses pygame to that:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
finished = False
isKeyPressed = False
while not finished:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if isKeyPressed:
            print "Key is currently pressed...Move forward!"
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finished = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                isKeyPressed = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                isKeyPressed = False
                #Perform action (here) when 'w' is unpressed 
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```